# How to limit manytomanyfields on a model?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I would like to check that I get not more than 3 relations set on a manytomanyfield.

I tried on the clean method to do this :

```
if self.tags.count()>3:
  raise ValidationError(_(u'You cannot add more than 3 tags'))
```

But `self.tags` returns not the current updates... only saved objects.

Do you have an idea to access to them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could do this a couple of ways.

First, you could do it as part of the model's save()

In your model, do something like this:

```
def save(self):
  # this may not be the correct check... but it will be something like this
  if self.tags.count() > 3: 
    # raise errors here
  else:
    super(MODEL_NAME,self).save()
```

Or you could do it manually in the view.

```
def some_view(request):

  # all the request.POST checking goes here

  the_model = form.save(commit=False)
  if the_model.tags.count() > 3:
    #error stuff
  else:
    the_model.save()
```

Comment: you could also do it on the form level and raise `form.ValidationError` if it does not meet your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Brant is correct. However, I think a better way to do what you want is to use three individual ForeignKey fields instead of one ManyToMany.

Comment: Your suggestion would present some problems, as the three foreign keys means null fields and precedence (first_tag is null, second_tag is 'food'), filtering that is difficult.